# Touchpad and wlan not working

Tags: wifi, touchpad

I just installed Elementary on my Lenovo S21e.
Looks really good but my touchpad and wifi are not working.
hope this can be solved.

greets, Maarten

Comment: Did the touchpad work during elementary OS installation?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to connect it to the internet somehow? I'm reading the specs and I see this model does not have an Ethernet port. 
If you can somehow (USB tethering from phone?) get online on it, run in Terminal:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

and then

`sudo apt install broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-dkms broadcom-sta-source`

Reboot.

Answer (score 1):

First enter `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Watch the video in the  link below it worked on my laptop, I too had that touchpad problem press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+t for opening the terminal and do what as suggested in the video and restart the system the touch pad works.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAPSrbZvsjk

Hope it works!!